# installing gphoto2 on a Pi

Tags: software-installation

I downloaded the .gz file from https://sourceforge.net/projects/gphoto/files/ (libgphoto2-2.5.16.tar.bz2), uncompressed it, un-tarred it.

Then from the command line, I ran

```
  autoreconf --install —symlink
  ./configure
  make
  sudo make install
```

There were no obvious errors, and if I go to `/usr/local/include` and `/usr/local/lib` I see relevant files. But I don't see the gphoto2 binary anywhere and trying to run gphoto2 results only in "command not found".

I am open to any suggestions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your issue is that you've installed the 'backend' library, `libgphoto2`, but not the front end command line tool, `gphoto2`. As noted in the documentation, [Finding what you need](http://gphoto.org/doc/manual/what-you-need.html):

> What you need:
>
> [...]
>
> - libgphoto2, some libgphoto2 frontend and (if you want to use USB cameras) libusb
>
> **libgphoto2 frontends**
>
> - gphoto2
>
>   Our own official command line interface (CLI) frontend. Simple command line interface and kind of a reference implementation. This libgphoto2 frontend is very useful for debugging camera drivers and other problems.

You can download and install the front end `gphoto2`  source from [here](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gphoto/files/gphoto/) (`gphoto2-2.5.15.tar.gz`). Once this is installed, you will be able to find and use the binary as expected. Alternatively, you can choose one of the other listed front ends, if you decide that you like one of those more.

Comment: You are correct, though now I'm getting `gphoto2: error while loading shared libraries: libgphoto2_port.so.12: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory` when I run the binary. Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I did a little digging, @Michael, and found [this thread](http://gphoto-software.10949.n7.nabble.com/Move-to-2-5-6-failed-td14945.html) which suggests that the libraries aren't in your linking path. Check `/etc/ld.so.conf` to see if `/usr/local/lib` is included, and if not, add it and rerun `ldconfig`.